why isn't tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization accepting standardization=None?
I'm still trying to get this work (and to learn!) so I am using a tiny corpus.
I do some preprocessing on the text in order to get specific bi-gram collocations using nltk (not relevant here but I have a list of compound nouns that I want to capture as a single token - this seemed a more sensible approach than running through the whole corpus for each word-pair that might only appear once).
So what I am passing to this vectorizing/ indexing step is a list of sentences that already have punctation, stopwords, numbers, etc. removed. with the exception of "_" between collocations. so for example ("fiery_pit"):
result
[...
'would far rather lay lengthwise along line equator yea ye gods',
 'go fiery_pit order keep frost',
 'lazarus lie stranded curbstone door dives wonderful iceberg moored one moluccas',
...]

from tensorflow import keras

vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=None,
    standardize=None,
    split="whitespace",
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=None
)

vectorizer.adapt(result)
vocab = vectorizer.get_vocabulary()
word_index = {word: index for index, word in enumerate(vocab)}
word_index
{'': 0,
 '[UNK]': 1,
 'whale': 2,
...
 'fiery': 927,
...}

It seems that punctuation is still being removed despite standardize=None. How do I fix this?
